# Android custom ListView not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create a custom listview using an ArrayAdapter with each row displaying an Image & TextView. I am using the following code but the application fails to run:

#### MainActivity.java

```
package demo.android.listviewadapter;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    
    String[]     buzzWords = {"Buzz-1", "Buzz-2", "Buzz-3", "Buzz-4", "Buzz-5", "Buzz-6", "Buzz-7"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);        
        setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.customlayout, R.id.txtName, buzzWords));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick (ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        
        Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked: " + buzzWords [position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### customlayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgName"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/txtName"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml` is the layout file which maps to the `MainActivity`. However, I use the `custom_layout.xml` file to customize the layout when assigning the adapter. Please can someone tell what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you are getting,can you post logcat/exception report?

Comment: Elaborate `not working` and `fails to run`

Comment: I receive the runtime error "**Unfortunately, ListViewAdapter has stopped**".

Comment: Post your LogCat exception, on lines with `RuntimeException....` `

Comment: **1** - You are not setting the content View in the onCreate method. **2** - The List id is wrong. **3** - You have to findViewById your Views. **4** - I also have doubts about this line: `setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.customlayout, R.id.txtName, buzzWords));`

Comment: **5** - `Unfortunately, ListViewAdapter has stopped` sounds like a NullPointerException (see points **3** and **4** in my previous comment).

Comment: Following is the LogCat exception:

Comment: 06-02 12:15:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(2980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 12:15:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(2980): Process: learn.android.listviewadapter, PID: 2980
06-02 12:15:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(2980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #6: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
06-02 12:15:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(2980):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
06-02 12:15:51.732: E/AndroidRuntime(2980):  at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using android `ListActivity` your `ListView` should have the id

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Please refer [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: Please follow all the constraints in the link. Please post the updated code as well

Comment: **Viswanath L*, I was missing the respective attribute. Added it in addition to what secofr said and it worked fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

missing

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

into the onCreate method

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);   
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.customlayout, R.id.txtName, buzzWords));
 }
```

and also..

into `activity_main.xml` replace `@+id/android:list` to `@android:id/list`

Comment: I tried your application in my enviroment, and after my directions works well; I had only put "android:layout_width" and "android:layout_height" attributes in the ImageView tag within the file customlayout.xml

Comment: **secofr,** you are right. I had not set the **layout_width** & **layout_height** for the ImageView. Did so and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom layout as 
**customlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="30sp" >
</TextView>
```

And change this

```
 setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.customlayout, R.id.txtName, buzzWords));
```

to this in `OnCreate` method

```
 setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.customlayout,buzzWords));
```